# How to expand.grid on vectors sets rather than single elements

Tags: r, tidyr

So, I have the following four vectors

```
a1 <- c(11, 12)
a2 <- c(21, 22)

b1 <- c(31, 32)
b2 <- c(41, 42)
```

and what I want to have in the end is a data frame that looks like

```
  p1 p2 p3 p4
1 11 12 31 32
2 21 22 31 32
3 11 12 41 42
4 21 22 41 42
```

i.e. every possible combination of the two `a` vectors with the two `b` vectors.

What I did is

```
ab <-  expand.grid(list(a1, a2), list(b1,b2))
ab.new <- ab %>% separate(Var1, c("p1", "p2"), sep = ",") 
             %>% separate(Var2, c("p3", "p4"), sep = ",")
```

and what I end up with is

```
    p1   p2   p3   p4
1 c(11  12) c(31  32)
2 c(21  22) c(31  32)
3 c(11  12) c(41  42)
4 c(21  22) c(41  42)
```

What are those `c(`s doing in there and how to get them out? Or, what did I do wrong in using `%>%`?

Comment: `%>%` is not the problem here, your data.frame `ab` does not contain characters but numeric vectors. when using `separate`, the entries are first converted into characters and then splitted. that's how you end up with the `c(`s

Comment: Can I suggest an edit to the title? How to expand.grid on vectors sets rather than single elements

Comment: @chinsoon12 good suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could try

```
do.call(cbind,lapply(expand.grid(list(a1, a2), list(b1,b2)),
               function(x) matrix(do.call(c, x), 4, 2, byrow=TRUE)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   11   12   31   32
#[2,]   21   22   31   32
#[3,]   11   12   41   42
#[4,]   21   22   41   42
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. But there should be an easier way to achieve this, no?

Comment: you can add `%>% data.table()` or `%>% data.frame()` at the end of akrun's code to get a data.table/frame instead of a matrix

Answer (score 0):

using only base to create a general function which expand.grid on sets of vectors:

```
permu.sets <- function(listoflist) {
    #assumes that each list within listoflist contains vectors of equal lengths
    temp <- expand.grid(listoflist)  
    do.call(cbind, lapply(temp, function(x) do.call(rbind, x)))
} #permu.sets

a1 <- c(11, 12)
a2 <- c(21, 22)
b1 <- c(31, 32)
b2 <- c(41, 42)
permu.sets(list(list(a1, a2), list(b1,b2)))
```

diff from @akrun answer is how to handle results from expand.grid without requiring dimensions being explicitly passed